# HTML Fonts that will work regardless of OS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, operating-system

I've been making a website, but the only fonts I could get working were Monospace, Arial, and the default (Times New Roman?) I tried to find a font like this:
[image]

I tried:
`<body style="font-family:tahoma;">`,
`<body style="font-family:cabin;">`,
and many others, but I couldn't find any fonts that would work. And the ones that did work all looked the same and were very ugly. Do you know of any fonts that would work regardless of operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your font looks the same in all OS you'll better use a font from a font provider like Google Fonts
for your case you can add this line in your header

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and after that try

```
<body style="font-family:Lato">
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be `Google Fonts`, easy to implement.

Link of reference list:
[Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/)

Example:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }     
 .bold { font-weight:600; }

 .bitter { font-family: 'Bitter', serif; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter|Lato" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>

<p>This font is <span class="bold">Open Sans</span></p>
<p class="bitter">This font is <span class="bold">Bitter</span></p>


</body>
</html>
```

An alternative, would be to create your own font with [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) (*Webfont Generator*)

Answer (score 1):

**Sans Serif**

- Arial
- Arial Black
- Tahoma
- Trebuchet MS
- Verdana

**Serif**

- Courier
- Courier New
- Georgia
- Times
- Times New Roman

**Monospace**

- Courier
- Courier New

https://templates.mailchimp.com/design/typography/